# Overwriting a File in Java

Tags: java, text-files

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(user + ".txt"));
    String time = t.toString();

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String [] check = line.split(";");
        date.add(check[0]);
        timeIn.add(check[1]);
        timeOut.add(check[2]);           
    }
    br.close();

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(user + ".txt"));

    if (timeOut.contains("not_out")){
        indx = timeOut.indexOf("not_out");
        timeOut.set(indx, time);       
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < date.size(); i++) {
        d =getDate(i);
        ti = ti(i);
        to = to(i);
        bw.write(d + ";" + ti + ";" + to);
        bw.newLine();   
    }          
    bw.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Time out error");
     e.printStackTrace();
}
return true;
```

The content of the text file is:

```
eg. 11/22/13;8:00;8:30
    11/23/13;8:00;not_out
```

Then I will replace `not_out` to the current time because I'm making a time-in and time-out program. 
But the always output is something like this:

```
  11/22/13;8:00;8:30
  11/22/13;8:00;8:30
  11/23/13;8:00;8:40
```

It always copies my first record.

Comment: are u closing file correctly after reading??? It seems like closed nowhere...

Comment: This is a very incomplete question, and you leave too many holes for us to be able to help. What does `ti(i)` do? What does `to(i)` do? What do they hold? Have you debugged these guys? Why aren't you using the timeIn and timeOut collections that you've filled? At the very least you should put in some println statements to see where your problem is.

Comment: Well the ti(i) is a method to get the elements inside the array list timeIn the to(i) is just like the ti method but it gets the elements in the array list timeOut .

Comment: @user3194331: **again**, have you checked what the ArrayList holds? Can you show us your methods and your ArrayList? Can you show us the code for the timeIn and timeOut variables?

Comment: yeah i already check my arraylists

Comment: public static String getDate(int i){
   String value = date.get(i);
   
   return value;
   
  }
  
  public static String ti(int i){
   
    String value = timeIn.get(i);
    return value;
  }
  
  public static  String to(int i){
           String value = timeOut.get(i);
            return value; 
             
  } my methods

Comment: Please avoid posting code in a comment since it is pretty much unreadable as it cannot be formatted. If you need to post code, post it as an edit to your original post/question, and well formatted at that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, and so is being posted as a "community wiki", but you absolutely need to do some basic debugging. You should in the least do something like:

```
try{

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(user+".txt"));

     String time = t.toString();

     while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
         String [] check = line.split(";");
         System.out.println("check: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(check));
         date.add(check[0]);
         timeIn.add(check[1]);
         timeOut.add(check[2]);
     }
     br.close();


     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(user+".txt"));


     if(timeOut.contains("not_out")){
        indx = timeOut.indexOf("not_out");
        timeOut.set(indx, time);       
     }

     for (int i = 0 ; i <date.size();i++ ){
        d =getDate(i);
        ti= ti(i);
        to= to(i);    

        // ***** added  *****
        System.out.printf("i: %d, d: %s, ti: %s, to: %s%n", i, d, ti, to);
        bw.write(d+";"+ti+";"+to);
        bw.newLine();
     }          
     bw.close();
   } catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("Time out error");
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return true;
}
```

And again you should show us more code including the `ti(...)` and `to(...)` variable.

Also, you should strive to only post well-formatted code when asking questions here, code with regular, well-placed indentations, with enough but not too much whitespace (especially not too many empty lines). You want to strive to make it *easy* for us to help you.

Comment: I think it's not the overwriting is the problem , thanks hovercraft in your comments yeah i realized that the problem is in my arraylist my previous data are not deleted that's why they are included in my writing. Now i think i should clear my array list first before putting elements again